# A reusable method for confirms in WinRT / Windows Store, using callbacks?

Tags: c#, callback, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've got the following long winded code for doing a confirm dialog in WinRT

```
IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncCommand = null;

var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to delete this file?", "Delete File");

// Add commands and set their callbacks
UICommand delete = new UICommand("Delete");
UICommand cancel = new UICommand("Cancel");

messageDialog.Commands.Add(delete);
messageDialog.Commands.Add(cancel);

messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;

IUICommand response = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

if (response == delete)
{
    // delete file                
}
```

Ok, it's not *that* long winded, but I'd love if there was some way to put it into a reusable method. This is what I have so far.

```
public void Confirm(String message, string title, string proceedButtonText, string cancelButtonText)
{
    IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncCommand = null;

    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);

    // Add commands and set their callbacks
    UICommand proceed = new UICommand(proceedButtonText);
    UICommand cancel = new UICommand(cancelButtonText);

    messageDialog.Commands.Add(proceed );
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(cancel);

    messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;

    IUICommand response = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

    if (response == proceed)
    {
        // how do I pass my function in here?           
    }
}
```

I can figure out passing the message, button names etc - but how do I pass my code / function for delete in there? I guess my question is how do I do a "callback" to run some code?

Comment: You could also return `response` (or a boolean) from `Confirm`. The caller of `Confirm` could then decide what code to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Action delegate, check sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted kiewic's answer as he pointed me in the right direction. However, I thought I'd share the full code here as an answer, in case anyone else wants to use it.

```
private async Task<IUICommand> Confirm(string message, string title, UICommand proceed, UICommand cancel, uint defaultCommandIndex = 1)
{
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);

    // Add commands and set their callbacks
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(proceed);
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(cancel);
    messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = defaultCommandIndex;

    return await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Call confirm like this:

```
await Confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?", "Delete File", 
    new UICommand("Delete", async (command) => {            
        // put your "delete" code here
    }), new UICommand("Cancel"));
```

You could further extend this by passing it a collection of `UICommand` objects instead - this would allow dialogs with more than two options

While I was at it I also wrote an alert method which saves some code when displaying a messaging dialogue.

```
private async Task<IUICommand> Alert(string message, string title = "Error")
{
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
    return await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

If you come from a web / js background like me, you might find these useful ;)